# How can I call a `callable` zval in php extension dev?

Tags: c, php-extension

If a zval is a callable object, how can I run it in my extension c code ?

or how to convert a `zval` to a `zend_fcall_info`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after search for the `zend_is_callable` and dive into the php src code, I know how to call a callable zval:

```
zval ret;

zval* params[] = { param }; // param is zval* too

if (SUCCESS == call_user_function(CG(function_table), NULL, callable, &retval, 1, params TSRMLS_CC)) {
    // callable is a zval*
    // you can do something with the retval now
}
```